# Why doesn't SQL "NOT IN ('val1')" return if the field is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I have a query like this one:

```
Select *
FROM table1
WHERE field1 NOT IN ('value1')
```

If the `field1` of the row is `null`, it will not be returned.
It doesn't look logical to me, because `null` is not 'value1', so the row should be returned, this can cause many bugs.
I understand that it's working like that because of some reasons. What are they?

Comment: NULL is an unknown value, so it cannot evalute the condition.

Comment: `Select * FROM table1 WHERE field1 NOT IN ('value1') OR field1 IS NULL;` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `NULL` is not a value, in SQL.

```
SELECT NULL = NULL
# => NULL
SELECT NULL != NULL
# => NULL
```

Thus,

> cause null is not 'value1'

but `NULL` is also not *not* 'value1'. `NULL` is basically the SQL way of saying "I don't know". So it might be 'value1', or it might not. The way to test for `NULL` is

```
SELECT NULL IS NULL;
# => 1
```

Thus, try this:

```
WHERE field1 NOT IN ('value1') OR field1 IS NULL
```

to specifically address the case.

Comment: Thank you. This a nice answer, and this is the solution I found when I understood the problem. My question is why is it like this? When does ot help?

Comment: [Some history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_\(SQL\)#History). The trivalent logic helps with reasoning about missing values: if you don't know Mr. Tanaka's family, you won't know how old are his sons, either. If you want to look for all fathers with underage sons, the answer for Mr. Tanaka is "I don't know", and he should not be included. But if you want to look for all fathers without underage sons, he should again not be included. The way it is implemented is that `NULL` "infects" the result of any operation - `1 + NULL IS NULL`, `LTRIM(NULL) IS NULL`... and `NULL` itself being falsy.

Answer (score 2):

`null` is not a value - it's the lack thereof. Think of it as missing data. Whenever it participates in a logical operator that works on values (such as `in`), it's result is "unknown" - "Question: is a missing value one the the following values? Answer: I don't know".

Since "unknown" ins't true, the row is not evaluated. If you want to handle `null`s you'd have to do so explicitly, e.g., by using the `in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  field1 IS NULL OR field1 NOT IN ('value1')
```

Comment: I'd think if SQL would have NO_VALUE and UNKNOWN_VALUE, it would be more intuitive... NULL is effectively latter, but people really think (and for a good reason) that it is the former.